# runtime datatype working in c, how does sizeof work?

Tags: c, pointers, runtime

As we know, we can use `int (*p)[10]` to define a pointer which points to an int[10] array, so if we have `p=0` and `sizeof(int)==4`, `p+1` will be `0+10*4 = 40`, this works because the compiler knows what p is when compiling.

And then what if we do it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int sz = 10;
    int (*p)[sz];
}
```

in other words, nobody would know the `sz` until the program runs there. I supposed this should not be working, but it does work..

So my question is, how it works? I mean, is there any place that store a value's type in c at runtime? If not, how this could work? Of this is just compiler-related?

I am using `gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)`, and you can test it with the following code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int COL ;
    int ROW ;
    scanf("%d %d", &COL, &ROW);
    int (*p)[COL];
    int *mem = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*COL*ROW);
    memset(mem,0,sizeof(int)*COL*ROW);
    p = (int (*)[10])mem;

    printf("0x%p\n", p);
    printf("COL=%d\n", p+1, (((int)(p+1))-((int)p))/sizeof(int));

    mem[2*COL+0] = 1;
    printf("%d\n", p[2][0]);
    mem[2*COL+5] = 2;
    printf("%d\n", p[2][5]);
    mem[6*COL+7] = 3;
    printf("%d\n", p[6][7]);

    p[1][2] = 4;
    printf("%d\n", mem[1*COL+2]);

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

I hope I am not asking a stupid question nor making stupid mistake...

Comment: i get a warning for that: `source.cpp:10:17: error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'p' [-Wvla]`

Comment: @Minion91, yes it should be like that, but gcc says nothing and the program works..

Comment: C allows variable length arrays(VLA) since c99 standard. So it also does allow pointer to arrays of variable lentghs.On the other hand C++ doesn't allow VLAs. C++ provides `std::vector` & `std::array` to acheive the same functionality.

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile time operator except when operating on variable length arrays, the C standard requires `sizeof` to determine the size of an VLA at runtime.

Comment: The compiler will generate code to perform multiplication by `sz` instead of multiplying by `10`. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic on variable length array types is well defined per 6.5.6:10, which has example code very similar to yours.  Per 6.5.3.4:2, when `sizeof` is applied to a variable length array, the operand is evaluated at runtime to determine the size, so variable length array pointer arithmetic proceeds likewise.

Variable length arrays (6.7.6.2:4) have been part of the standard since the second edition (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 as amended); they are however an optional feature that conformant implementations do not have to support (6.10.8.3).

Comment: how to evaluate it? is there something say p is a int(*)[sz], and find sz to evaluate p..?

Comment: @Marcus the implementation finds the initial declaration of `p` i.e. `int (*p)[sz]`, and evaluates `sz`.

Comment: so the when the compiler see p+1, it will generate something like `offset = sizeof(int)*sz; retrun p+offset`?

Comment: thanks, and that's quite straightforward... I should have figured out.